# What is the correct verb to use, is or was

Tags: american-english, british-english, spoken-english

What is the correct verb to use

> My approved OT for the month of Feb is 127.5 hours, but only 8.5 hours was creditted last night, 119 hours unpaid.

The situation is one of our workmate's Overtime pay was not credited on this month's payroll and he issending email to the "Human Resources" to clarify it.

Comment: Can you add a few more details.  When are you saying this? Why do you think this might be a difficult case? What do you think is the correct answer and why? Why have you tagged both British and American (one tag or neither and only if you think the question is only for one dialect) All these details will make the answers more useful for you and others.

Comment: Me and my friends are arguing about this for hours and we are still confused on what verb to use. To give you the background, the situation is one of our workmate's OT pay was not credited on this month's payroll and he issending email to the HR to clarify it.

Comment: They are both correct, with different meaning. Please explain the context of the discussion, so we can understand what you have in mind / what your colleagues have in mind.

Comment: Here is the complete sentence. My approved OT for the month of Feb is 127.5 hours, but only 8.5 hours was creditted last night, 119 hours unpaid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "is" and "was" could be used here. There is a slight change in perspective. "Was" suggests the overtime is past and you are talking about past events. "Is" suggests you are talking about the present state of approval.

As this is only March, you may feel that the "overtime+approval" is still present, so use the present tense verb. You may equally feel that it is a past event and choose the past tense.

If you were talking about this in September (for example) you'd be much more likely to choose past tense.